# Updating Ruby on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos

I was trying to install rails and also tried to update gem, but it didn't work out.Tried to google the problem and it says i have older version of ruby which i have to update. I currently have 1.8.6 . Can somebody please help me how to update this version to 1.9?

Comment: I suggest you to look at [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

Comment: This could be easily solved via a quick search. Google "install Ruby 1.9 on mac os x".

Comment: Do NOT upgrade the Ruby that Apple installed. That is theirs, for their purposes. Instead, as the answers recommend, use RVM. Follow the instructions on the [install](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) page.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io).

Read the site, there are step-by-step manuals.

Answer (score 1):

I suugest you to go to the terminal and using from rvm.